# Crawl error in Project server 2010 error is: The object was not found

Tags: 2010, enterprise-search, project-server

[image]

When I'm trying to crawl getting this error and I don't know what to do. I can see almost **37 errors** of the above attached error screenshot. It's a **Project server 2010**.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure couple of things on the Index/ crawl server.

- are you able to access the Project Server ULR from that server?
- have you disable the loopback check on the search server?
- Any host file entry on the Search server which bypass the main url?
- Check IIS bindings and make sure they correct?
- make sure Default content access account properly registered.

Comment: Tried each and every step but couldn't find the use but can you please explain about 3rd and 4th points please

Comment: on the server if you go the host file and see any entry except default one...should be located here C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and also check in the IIS for the Project web app about the bindings.